# tsql LIKE wildcard comparison finds what = does not

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This:

```sql
select casenumber from case where casenumber = '21-CR-1019'
```

Returns:
Nothing

While this:

```sql
select casenumber from case where casenumber like '%21-CR-1019%'
```

Returns:
`21-CR-1019`

The table column definition is varchar(20). I don't think that's a factor.

I checked the data source and didn't find a padded string. Nor does there appear to be a padded string in the value, since the length returned matches the actual string length:

This:

```sql
select casenumber, len(casenumber) as StringLength from case where casenumber like '%21-CR-1019%'
```

Returns:

```
casenumber  StringLength
2021-CR-1019    12
```

This is SQL Server Standard Edition, 10.50.6560.0 (SQL Server 2008R2).

Does anyone know if there's an explanation for this behavior? I've never, ever seen it.

Does the mix of characters and integers somehow confuse the ability of tsql to infer a data type? Is this a "feature"?

Comment: Note that `21-CR-1019` is not the same as `2021-CR-1019`.

Comment: What? Oh my gosh. You're so right. <DopeSlap> I'm going for another cup of coffee. I guess I started down that path because it was read to me to search in a shorthand without the "20". Still not a valid excuse.

Comment: So what value is it actually returning? When you just have `select casenumber` you say that `casenumber` has the value `'21-CR-1019'` but when you use `select casenumber, len(casenumber) ` `casenumber` has the value `'2021-CR-1019'`.

Comment: Obligatory note that SQL Server 2008(R2) has been *completely* unsupported for 3 years now, and you *really* need to get that upgrade path finalised.

Comment: The behavior you see is the same for all databases. One is looking for an exact match, the other for a substring. The real difference is that the second one will have to scan the entire table, because substring searches can't use any indexes

Comment: I'm not the DBA, but yes, when I searched for the version that's running, I made the same conclusion about the version being unsupported.

Comment: Another obligatory note, the earliest version in mainstream support is SQL Server 2017 which allows running Python scripts in the database using and producing query results. Which means you can use all those nice text processing packages and fuzzy match operators. The built-in distribution is more-or-less a Conda  distribution

Comment: The lack of RegEx tools has been such a weakness! So I'm very pleased to hear about the Python option. I didn't know that. Thank you!

Related article I just found: 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6459/sql-server-regex-capabilities-using-python/

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning 504more!

Yeah, sometimes when it comes to years, we like to think 2021 but accidently only type in 21..
So in your first one.. it's looking for exactly 21-CR-1019, so it doesn't find it.
In your second one, you have the wildcard.. and it finds a match because it finds **20**21-CR-1019

Once you said that it was measuring the length as 12.. i knew that your first search was for only 10 characters.

I'm glad I could help you out with that :)